# Assign a "value" to a particular observation in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have frequency counts that line up with a set number of states of the world

Data=

```
S <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
n <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
df<- data.frame(S,n)
```

I want to create some values that line up with the n values for each, named with the relevant subscripts:

Pa = n for state a
Pb = n for state b
etc.

Even though I can go:

```
Pa <- 1
Pb <- 2
```

I will be using a lot of different dataframes that use the sames states but that will yield different values of n each time.

I fear that this is a horribly basic question but what can I do to create a Pa value for every possible n that lines up with state a?

Comment: Can you clarify more what you're looking for? `df$states = paste0("P",df$S)`?

Comment: I'm wary about any approach in R that relies on a bunch of free-floating variables; it's probably going to be more robust to put the values you want to reference into a list or a data frame. But it's unclear in the question how you want to use these or how they're supposed to be generated. What tells us what value of `n` goes with what states?

Comment: Sorry @JonSpring , I am not sure how to respond to the first question.

I am working from a data set of about 6000 observations at the moment, that has a column for states of the world S.

From that I have generated a frequency table for the S column that exists on its own. So the n is just the frequency of variable s in the original df. The issue I have is that the df will change and I want to have a sort of generalized code!

Comment: Please have another go at editing the question to clarify what information you have, what result you want, and what logic gets you there.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a simple example to see if it is what you are trying to do:

```
set.seed(42)
states <- sample(letters[1:5], 25, replace=TRUE)
tbl <- table(states)
tbl
# states
# a b c d e 
# 7 6 2 5 5 
states.df <- data.frame(tbl)
states.df
#   states Freq
# 1      a    7
# 2      b    6
# 3      c    2
# 4      d    5
# 5      e    5
```

The result is a data frame showing the frequency for each state. You can easily reference these values in your code without creating variables for each row, but it is possible to do so:

```
ls()
# [1] "states"    "states.df" "tbl"    
for(i in seq(nrow(states.df))) assign(paste0("P", states.df[i, 1]), states.df[i, 2])
ls()
# [1] "i"         "Pa"        "Pb"        "Pc"        "Pd"        "Pe"        "states"    "states.df"
[9] "tbl"      
Pa
# [1] 7
Pe
# [1] 5
```

Comment: Hi @dcarlson, thanks for the reply! I have no trouble getting this far, what I want to do is to create values Pa, Pb, [...] Pe that refer to the frequency of each state A, B [...] E but that can be applied to a variety of different dataframes. 

I am trying to build a general function which calls on Pa, Pb, etc., as part of a pipe that first generates the frequency table, then applies the function. What I am hoping for is that I will be able to simply change the df that the pipe (and therefore function) are working on and generate the different results without having to rewrite each time

Comment: So call the frequency of state A = Pa ---
and for df1 Pa = 7, df2 has Pa = 8, df3 has Pa = 4, ---
Assuming that the bones of the frequency table object is the same for all df, only the actually frequencies change, I want to create a Pa that always refers to the same cell for every df.

Comment: I agree with @JonSpring. If you would describe what you are trying to accomplish instead of how you want to do it, I'm sure there is a simpler, more efficient way of getting there.

Comment: I have added a way to create the separate variables, Pa, Pb, etc as you requested.

Comment: "I want to create a Pa that always refers to the same cell for every df"? Still unclear to me whether the state frequencies are global assumptions (in which case they should live in a table) or are specific to each source df and derived from the df (in which case that could be a table scoped within a function).

Comment: "create a Pa that always refers to the same cell for every df" --- is this a lookup from  an excel file (where "cell" is more common terminology)?

Comment: I do not know what the OP is trying to accomplish. The code I provided could be wrapped into a function that takes the `df` as an argument and then creates the P variables from that particular `df`. This might make sense if code already exists referencing those variables and revising the code to make it more flexible would be difficult.

Comment: @dcarlson "You can easily reference these values in your code without creating variables for each row" 

can you please explain this to me? this might just be the easiest solution?

Comment: I am sorry, I really don't know how to explain what I am after differently from how I have already put it! Thanks both for your time, I may just have to look for a different way to go forward.

Comment: As I said above "If you would describe what you are trying to accomplish instead of how you want to do it, I'm sure there is a simpler, more efficient way of getting there."